# WordPress - how to route all requests back to index

Tags: wordpress, angularjs

I am experimenting with using WordPress and Angular JS together through the WP-API plugin. I'd like to have WordPress just serve content through a JSON API and let Angular take care of everything else; routing etc. 
To do this I need all requests to my site to go back to my home page, where Angular can then read the URL and load the appropriate view. I'm using Angular UI Router to get extra options here.

I've deleted all the WordPress theme files apart from header.php and footer.php and this means URLs like http://mywordpresssite.com/route work. WordPress routes back to index and Angular reads route.

But, when I make a request like http://mywordpresssite.com/route/parameter I get sent straight back to index.

I don't know what I should be looking at to make this work. Can this be done in the .htaccess file or should I be writing custom routes into WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

If i undetstand you correctly. You shuld create a theme with angular and put all your ajax stuf in functions.php file. Wordpress has suport for ajax. Then you can call that functions from angular theme in your desired format.

Sorry that I do not include some examples but I weiting from mobile.

Let me know if I got your problem

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but you are not addressing my question. I have already set up the WP-API plugin, so I'm not having problems getting my data in JSON format. My problem is with the routing in WordPress and Angular

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a very similar project you can find here:
https://github.com/altrovideo/wordpress-angularjs

the way I've chosen is quite different: I've decided to abandon any front-end wordpress code, so I've written an empty sub-directory in the theme dir , then I put there my html + js + css files using https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

for pagination I use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap and I'm using angular routing module and it works well.

Maybe the presence of wordpress headers.php files and using it as a classical wordpress theme should create the trouble.

Let me know if it helps you

Comment: This is the way I've seen most people doing it. I don't see it as ideal, as I feel it means missing out on a lot of useful functionality that WordPress provides in its themes. Thanks for the input